# How to target nested objects and refer to THIS property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to change the state of opening/closing times (and then post to an endpoint) on multiple days which are returned to me in an object like so:

[image]

I have rendered these in a React component:

```
{this.state.time.map(each => (
    <Fragment key={each.code}>
        <OpeningHours
            code={each.code}
            day={each.description}
            name={each.code}
            open={each.open !== null ? each.open : '00:00'}
            close={each.close !== null ? each.close : '00:00'}
            onChange={this.onTimeChange}
        />
    </Fragment>
))}
```

[image]

The user will set these times by manually editing the time input. How would I get `this` open or close property of the day being edited and then store that in the `time` state? So far I've tried this, which works, but only if there was just an opening time or one field in general. The issue arises since I have 2 fields to edit:

```
onTimeChange(e) {
  let times = this.state.time.slice();
  for(let i in time){
      if(times [i].name == event.target.name){
          times [i].value = event.target.value;
          this.setState ({time});
          break;
      }
  }
}
```

EDIT: OpeningHours component

```
const OpeningHours = props => (
    <div className={styles.block}>
        <label htmlFor={props.code} className={styles.label}>{props.day}</label>
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <input
                type="time"
                name={props.name}
                value={props.open !== null ? props.open : '00:00'}
                onChange={props.onChange}
                className={styles.timefield}
            />
            <input
                type="time"
                name={props.name}
                value={props.close !== null ? props.close : '00:00'}
                onChange={props.onChange}
                className={styles.timefield}
            />
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Can you also show the `OpeningHours` component, or at least, where it calls `onChange`

Comment: you could add a second callback to the `OpeningHours` component for when the closing hour changes. So you have one for opening and one for closing.

Comment: @Treycos Added the component above

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this could be to pass more information to the `onChange` function about what is actually changing.

```
onTimeChange(field, e) {
  let times = this.state.time.slice();
  for(let i in time){
      if(times [i].name == event.target.name){
          if(field === 'open') {
              times [i].open = event.target.value;
              this.setState ({time});
              break;
          } else if (field === 'closed') {
              times [i].closed = event.target.value;
              this.setState ({time});
              break;
          }
      }
}
```

This would require a slight change to your input components:

```
<input
  type="time"
  name={props.name}
  value={props.open !== null ? props.open : '00:00'}
  onChange={ e => props.onChange('open', e) }
  className={styles.timefield}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind identifying information to the onChange function and then use that to make the changes.

```
`<input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, props.code)}</input>`
```

Here is an example of how data is bound: https://jsfiddle.net/jphuangjr/aq7mtfgo/112/